# create a new variable based on existing variables by using tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to create a new variable "race" with 4 categories (Black/Latino/White/Others) in my dataset "**data2**" (see table below).
The conditions I want to apply are:

1. Anyone indicating '**Hispanic or Latino**' is coded as **Latino**, regardless if they indicated other options of race.
2. Those who indicated **'Black' (only)** would be coded **Black**
3. Those who indicated **'White' (only)** would be coded **White**
4. Those who indicated **'Asian' or 'Native American'**, or **'others'**, OR indicated more than one option (unless Hispanic or Latino), would be coded **Others**

I want to use  `mutate` and `case_when` function to create a new variable **race** following the condition above.

race_1 - Asian
race_2 - Black
race_3 - Hispanic or Latino
race_4 - Native American
race_5 - White
race_6 - others

| race_1 | race_2 | race_3 | race_4 | race_5 | race_6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NA | 1 | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | 1 | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | 1 | NA | NA | NA |
| 1 | NA | 1 | NA | 1 | NA |
| NA | NA | NA | NA | 1 | NA |
| NA | NA | 1 | NA | NA | NA |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
dat %>%
  # convert `NA` to false, all others to true ... verify this is what you want
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("race_")), ~ !is.na(.)) %>%
  # provide a variable that lists how many races were selected
  mutate(combined = rowSums(across(starts_with("race_")))) %>%
  mutate(race = case_when(
    race_3                 ~ "Latino",
    race_2 & combined == 1 ~ "Black",
    race_5 & combined == 1 ~ "White",
    TRUE                   ~ "Others")
  )
#   race_1 race_2 race_3 race_4 race_5 race_6 combined results
# 1  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE        1   Black
# 2  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE        1  Latino
# 3  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE        1  Latino
# 4   TRUE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE        3  Latino
# 5  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE        1   White
# 6  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE        1  Latino
```

Comment: Thanks. I used your code but it indicates some errors:  

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `combined`.
x 'x' must be numeric
ℹ Input `combined` is `rowSums(across(starts_with("race_")))`.

Comment: It sounds like you have a `factor` or perhaps I'm missing something else. Please provide usable unambiguous data, typically one of `data.frame(..)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`. Thanks!

Comment: the "race_" variables are numiric. and I did ```dput(data2)```  this is the outcome:   race_1 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), race_2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
1, NA, NA), race_3 = c(1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1), race_4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 1, NA, NA), race_5 = c(1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1), race_6 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)

Comment: Comments are unfortunately horrible for significant data/code, and you can see why. Further, that is the abridged output, as it should always start with `structure`. We need the entire output of `structure` to be able to use it. If it's too much, then limit the data going into it, as in `dput(data2[1:5,1:6])` or so. Finally, please put that into your original question as a code block. Thanks!

Comment: hmmm, I am not quite sure what do you mean by abridged output or unambiguous data, also what do you mean by starting with structure... English in statistics and programming are so different than my native language... I will try to use your proposed code above again. THANKS!

Comment: @Dr.KnowNothing he is saying (a) Please do not put the sample data from `dput()` down here in the comments. Edit your question and put it in your question. (b) There are several reasons for this, but the biggest one is that what you put in the comment above is not complete. It should start with `structure(`. What you put above does not start with `structure(` so we know it is missing important parts.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @GregorThomas. The result I got from `dput` is a long list of stuff of 200+ variables in the dataset. But I assume you only want to see what's there for the selected race variables. Also, I don't even know what do you mean by starting with `structure(`....I think I may need more basics to understand the terminology before asking these questions...Thanks!

Comment: Can you try my suggestion of `dput(data2[1:5,1:6])`? The numbers 5 and 6 likely need to be tweaked, but the premise is that you give us a relevant subset of rows and columns.

Comment: When you type `dput(mtcars)`, for instance, the output on the console starts with `structure(list(mpg = c(21, 21, 22.8, ...`. *That's what we mean* by starting with `structure(`. While we can add that, that works only if that is the only thing wrong with it. In your comment, we're also missing at least the last portion, which is likely `class="data.frame"`, but ... again, the reason we often prefer `dput` is that it will tell us much about the structure that you may not know or may not think relevant for your question.